# Bourbon and Neat with Meteor

Tags: meteor

Trying to use Bourbon and Neat with my Meteor project. I keep getting issues when trying to run the server. I'm trying to use this package https://atmospherejs.com/wolves/neat but get this error:

```
   While processing files with fourseven:scss (for target web.browser):
   /client/stylesheets/main.scss: Scss compiler error: File to import:
   {wolves:bourbon}/bourbon not found. Import origin:
   /client/stylesheets/main.scss
```

Any one have a fix or alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Stop the app and restart it:

[Docs:](https://atmospherejs.com/wolves/neat)

> Because Meteor will attempt to compile you app's local stylesheets
>   prior to copying the server assets directory, the first time you run
>   the app after installing the package your app will complain that it is
>   unable to find it. **For the moment this can be resolved by** either
>   **stopping and restarting the app**, at which point you should no longer
>   get this error message, or running touch on you local stylesheet
>   thats attempting to access the package, triggering a reload.

Answer (score 0):

So both plugins broke with the latest version of Meteor. I had to explicitly state which versions of Wolfe's Neat and Bourbon to use.

```
meteor add wolves:bourbon@3.1.0
meteor add wolves:neat@3.1.0
```

Then just make sure you import the files as stated in the documentation and no more issue!